# Upload a library photo with Android web browser

Tags: javascript, android, api, upload, camera

As  is disabled on Android, is it possible to upload a photo from library, in Browser somehow? Camera/Photo Library JavaScript API?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The webkit browser in version 2.2 (Froyo) supports file uploads via the typical HTML form mechanism:

Comment: I think this answer is not acceptable, given the Android fragmentation. Compatibility is, I believe quite important, and we'll have to wait some time before it's really available to Android users. Besides, almost no actual phones has Froyo yet.

Comment: A number of the Verizon Android phones do have 2.2, mine (an HTC Incredible) included. And, I tested file uploads on it. That said, I completely agree that compatibility is important, however, I don't presume to know elado's situation. It's possible that depending on Froyo is better than no solution at all.

Comment: well, as of this comment 28.7% of Android installations are currently running Froyo: http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if there is a specific place you want to upload pictures to, but I just wrote an app that does this. It uploads to Flickr and works with Android 1.6. Take a look at http://www.flickr.com/services/api/

Multi-part POST is the tricky part, and to do that you need to include apache-mime4j-0.6.jar and httpmime-4.0.3.jar.

```
        MultipartEntity mp = new MultipartEntity(
            HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    for (String key : params.keySet()) {
        try {
            mp.addPart(key, new StringBody(params.get(key), UTF_8));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            // UTF-8 is always supported
        }
    }
```

Comment: question is about browser functionality, not native apps.