# Uploading photos in Android browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, upload, ios6

The problem is simple: I'd like to create a web page that, when viewed in the browser on Android devices, allows users to either select an image from their existing photos or use the camera to take a photo, and then uploads the photo (presumably as part of a multipart form post).

iOS6 supports exactly this functionality for HTML form elements (e.g. `<input type="file" />`.  Is comparable functionality available for browsers on Android devices?  If so... how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392214/upload-a-library-photo-with-android-web-browser?rq=1 indicates this might be possile as of Android 2.2...?  Has anyone tested this?   If so, then it appears the majority of Android devices should be capable of this: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html